# Two dimensional embedding

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Take $ \alpha\gt0$ and consider $\Omega=\{ x \in R^2: x_1^2+x_2^2 \lt 1, x_i\gt 0 \}$  (first quadrant of unit ball in plane).  I am interested in optimal (so I am looking for the range of $p$) embeddings of the form
$$ \left( \int_\Omega | u(x)|^p |x|^\alpha x_1^{m-1} x_2^{n-1} dx \right)^\frac{2}{p} \le C \int_\Omega \left( u_{x_1}^2 + u_{x_2}^2 \right) x_1^{m-1} x_2^{n-1} dx $$ for all smooth functions $u$ which are zero on the curved portion of the boundary and where $m,n$ are positive integers.

Any comments would be appreciated.   I asked a very similar question here [Sobolev imbedding result; proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392117/sobolev-imbedding-result-proof/392171?noredirect=1#comment1012845_392171)